# Camel does not delete camelLock file after finishing route test

Tags: java, testing, apache-camel

I'm learning Apache camel from the "Camel in Action" book and currently I'm on data transformation. More particularly Content Enricher EIP. I noticed that when I run the code below from the book Camel creates fileName + .camelLock file but it doesn't remove it after finishing route.

Is there something wrong from the code side ? Or it should work like that ?

```
import java.io.File;

import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.processor.aggregate.AggregationStrategy;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit4.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.Test;

public class OrderToCsvProcessorTest extends CamelTestSupport {

    @Test
    public void testOrderToCsvProcessor() throws Exception {
        // this is the inhouse format we want to transform to CSV
        String inhouse = "0000004444000001212320091208  1217@1478@2132";
        template.sendBodyAndHeader("direct:start", inhouse, "Date", "20091208");

        File file = new File("target/orders/received/report-20091208.csv");
        assertTrue("File should exist", file.exists());

        // compare the expected file content
        String body = context.getTypeConverter().convertTo(String.class, file);
        assertEquals("000000444,20091208,000001212,1217,1478,2132\nthis,is,sample,string", body);
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder createRouteBuilder() throws Exception {
        return new RouteBuilder() {
            @Override
            public void configure() throws Exception {
                from("direct:start")
                        .process(new OrderToCsvProcessor())
                        .pollEnrich("file://target/input?noop=true",
                                new AggregationStrategy() {
                                    @Override
                                    public Exchange aggregate( Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {
                                        if (newExchange == null) {
                                            return oldExchange;
                                        }

                                        String http = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);
                                        String ftp = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

                                        String body = http + "\n" + ftp;

                                        oldExchange.getIn().setBody(body);

                                        return oldExchange;
                                    }
                                })
                        .to("file://target/orders/received?fileName=report-${header.Date}.csv");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

Processor which is used in code:

```
import org.apache.camel.Exchange;
import org.apache.camel.Processor;

public class OrderToCsvProcessor implements Processor {

    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
        String custom = exchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

        String id = custom.substring(0, 9);
        String customerId = custom.substring(10, 19);
        String date = custom.substring(20, 29);
        String items = custom.substring(30);
        String[] itemIds = items.split("@");

        StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder();
        csv.append(id.trim());
        csv.append(",").append(date.trim());
        csv.append(",").append(customerId.trim());
        for (String item : itemIds) {
            csv.append(",").append(item.trim());
        }

        exchange.getIn().setBody(csv.toString());
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

GenericFileOnCompletion is in charge of deleting the lock file. You need to handoverCompletions in AggregationStrategy just like this.

```
new AggregationStrategy() { 
  @Override
   public Exchange aggregate( Exchange oldExchange, Exchange newExchange) {    if (newExchange == null) {
      return oldExchange;    }

   String http = oldExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);    String ftp = newExchange.getIn().getBody(String.class);

   String body = http + "\n" + ftp;

   oldExchange.getIn().setBody(body);
     newExchange.handoverCompletions(oldExchange);

   return oldExchange;  } })
```

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. The file still exists after this change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is due to the fact that you are pulling a file using pollEnrich with a **custom AggregationStrategy**.

When using a custom AggregationStrategy in this use case, then certain properties of the aggregated Exchange need to be copied over to the original Exchange for the Camel markerFile to be deleted correctly

So, at the end of your AggregationStrategy you can do :

```java
oldExchange.getProperties().putAll(newExchange.getProperties());
```

Source : https://access.redhat.com/solutions/2189891